# Background Image in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to display an image as the background of the body of a page and it needs to work in IE8.

At the moment I have the following which works but I would rather allow the image to scale in proportion to the window size, at the moment the image is displaying at a size of 100%, instead it should fill the browser window and scale as the window changes.

```
<div id="bg">
    <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#bg {
    position:fixed; 
    top:-50%; 
    left:-50%; 
    width:200%; 
    height:200%;
}
#bg img {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    right:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    margin:auto; 
    min-width:50%;
    min-height:50%;
}
```

Comment: I don't get the position values of the bg div. Why not just do: `top: px; left: 0px`  etc.?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: @Pekka I was copying code from Sean's link

Comment: @Sean If you look at that page I am actually using that code, problem is that for IE8 it still displays the bg image at full size

Comment: The technique you're using fails in IE8 (he mentions that at the bottom) Can you use the jQuery technique? it works all the way back to 7.

Comment: @Sean thank you, yes the jQuery technique worked.